# Incoparable Java Types boolean and object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have this piece of code which worked in Java 6

```
if(false==sess.getAttribute("admin") || null==sess.getAttribute("admin"))
        {
            res.sendRedirect("/myapp/login.jsp?errmsg=You must log in as an administrator to manage resources");
            return;
        }
```

I want to familiarize myself with the new features of Java 7 and what it offers new in javaee hence I upgraded netbeans to 7.4 and jdk 7u45.
My project opened successfully however the file with this code is marked as a java class with an error by netbeans. Running the project I get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incomparable types: boolean and java.lang.Object
```

What I want to ask is why this worked in java6 and doesn't work in java7

**FYI** `HttpSession sess = req.getSession();`

Comment: I don't believe the code compiled successfully in java 6.

Comment: It did. That is why I am asking.

Comment: I want you to take that java file and compile it individually with java 6.  Then post the contents of the file and the output of javac.

Answer (score 2):

HttpSession.getAttribute returns an Object.
Change the line to `(Boolean.FALSE==sess.getAtrribute)`

Looks like autoboxing (boolean to Boolean) has changed in Java.
Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your error. I have seen a similar error message in the same Netbeans 7.4/jdk 7u45.
My code:

```
if (true == evt.getNewValue())
```

(where evt is a PropertyChangeEvent)
The message in Netbeans (when I hover over the red cross left to the statement) says "incomparable types: boolean and Object". Notice the difference with your message: the missing "java/lang" before Object.
And even stranger: my code compiles without any problem.
Compiler options in Netbeans are: "-version -Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation"

Answer (score 1):

You should try with

```
if(false==(Boolean)sess.getAttribute("admin") || null==sess.getAttribute("admin"))
    {
        res.sendRedirect("/myapp/login.jsp?errmsg=You must log in as an administrator to     manage resources");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute probably returns either an Object or a `boolean`. If it returns a `boolean`, then `null==getAttrubute` will not work and if it returns an `Object` then `false==getAttribute` will fail.

Comment: True. But this does not explain why it worked perfectly in java6 and not working in java7